# Call jQuery function from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick

I have this code and I am trying do call a function, but it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I need to do to fix this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function BoxMsg(mess) {
    $.MessageBox(mess);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="rxc021" name="rxc021" type="button" class="e-btn e-btn-border" value="Ask" onclick="BoxMsg('rxc021 - option 1')">
<input id="rxc022" name="rxc022" type="button" class="e-btn e-btn-border" value="Ask" onclick="BoxMsg('rxc022 - option 2')">
<input id="rxc023" name="rxc023" type="button" class="e-btn e-btn-border" value="Ask" onclick="BoxMsg('rxc023 - option 3')">
<input id="rxc024" name="rxc024" type="button" class="e-btn e-btn-border" value="Ask" onclick="BoxMsg('rxc024 - option 4')">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For functions referenced by `onclick` attributes they need to be placed in global scope. As your function is defined in document.ready, it's not in scope. To fix the problem, move your function definition:

```js
function BoxMsg(mess) {
  $.MessageBox(mess);
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gasparesganga-jquery-message-box@3.2.2/dist/messagebox.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gasparesganga-jquery-message-box@3.2.2/dist/messagebox.min.css" />
<input id="rxc021" name="rxc021" type="button" class="e-btn e-btn-border" value="Ask" onclick="BoxMsg('rxc021 - option 1')">
<input id="rxc022" name="rxc022" type="button" class="e-btn e-btn-border" value="Ask" onclick="BoxMsg('rxc022 - option 2')">
<input id="rxc023" name="rxc023" type="button" class="e-btn e-btn-border" value="Ask" onclick="BoxMsg('rxc023 - option 3')">
<input id="rxc024" name="rxc024" type="button" class="e-btn e-btn-border" value="Ask" onclick="BoxMsg('rxc024 - option 4')">
```

Better still, *do not use `onclick`*. It's outdated and not good practice.

The better alternative is to use unobtrusive event handlers bound in your JS code, not the HTML. You can use `data` attributes to retrieve element metadata within these event handlers:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.e-btn').on('click', e => {
    let $btn = $(e.target);
    $.MessageBox($btn.data('message'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gasparesganga-jquery-message-box@3.2.2/dist/messagebox.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gasparesganga-jquery-message-box@3.2.2/dist/messagebox.min.css" />
<input id="rxc021" name="rxc021" type="button" class="e-btn e-btn-border" value="Ask" data-message="rxc021 - option 1" />
<input id="rxc022" name="rxc022" type="button" class="e-btn e-btn-border" value="Ask" data-message="rxc022 - option 2" />
<input id="rxc023" name="rxc023" type="button" class="e-btn e-btn-border" value="Ask" data-message="rxc023 - option 3" />
<input id="rxc024" name="rxc024" type="button" class="e-btn e-btn-border" value="Ask" data-message="rxc024 - option 4" />
```